# Magento2 override block from theme level without custom module

Tags: magento2, blocks, theme, overrides

I currently have a Magento_Shipping folder in my theme which is overriding the frontend files from magento/module-shipping

Is it possible for me to override the block files from theme level without having to create a new custom module?

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible !

`app/code` : directory contain custom module folders

`app/design`: directory contain custom theme folders

We agree that the your block file is located in `module_shipping/Block` and not in `module_shipping/view` ? If so, you can't, you need to rewrite it in `app/code`.

Comment: I was told it was possible some way, so does it need to be a custom module to extend the whole of module-shipping?

Comment: Not the whole module-shipping, you just rewrite the block file that you need in your custom module in `app/code/`

Comment: Is it not cleaner to do the theme level stuff in the module too rather than having a module to edit block files and code in the theme too?

Comment: if you create a custom module for that, yes you can put your design files directly in this module and they will have priority over those of the theme. Good luck.